# Binning values in a vector

Tags: r, binning

I'm trying to 'bin' numbers which are beats per minute (BPM) into heart rate; the number of BPMs per time. I'm trying to keep the most similar consecutive numbers together as 1 heart rate. For example, if the BPM was

```
x <- c(15.1, 15.2, 15.3, 20.1, 20.2, 20.3)
```

over 6 seconds (each BPM is an average for that second), I'd like to interpret this as 2 heart rates per 6 seconds.

Comment: Have you explored `?cut`

Answer (score 2):

Using your example. You define and play with `cut` to define the breaks you want and then `table` to create a frequency table with the occurrences for each group.

```
hr <- c(15.1, 15.2, 15.3, 20.1, 20.2, 20.3)
groups<- cut(hr,breaks = 2)
as.data.frame(table(groups))
```

Output:

```
       groups Freq
1 (15.1,17.7]    3
2 (17.7,20.3]    3
```